# How to secure php session? I still can use curl (Linux) to see source code

Tags: php

I try to secure my webpage login on my Debian server with a php session. I have the following files:

```
|-- index.php
|-- site.php
|-- php
|   |-- config.php
|   |-- login.php
|   `-- session.php
```

In "config.php" my connection with MySQL is written. In "login.php" I check the database for a valid login and tell the session the username of the user and redirects to "site.php".

```
if (password_verify($password, $passwordInDatabase)) {

  $_SESSION['login_user'] = $username;
  $_SESSION["admin"] = true;

  header("location: site.php");

  } else {

    $error = "Please, try again.";

  }
```

In "session.php" I create a session cookie, when you do not have a session cookie you will be redirected to index.php:

```
include('php/config.php');
session_start([
'cookie_lifetime' => 86400,
'read_and_close'  => true,
]);

if(!isset($_SESSION['login_user']))
  header("location:index.php");
```

my php.ini file important lines:

```
session.save_handler = files
session.use_cookies = 1
session.cookie_secure = 1
session.use_only_cookies = 1
session.cookie_domain = "example.com"
session.cookie_httponly = 1
session.entropy_length = 32
session.entropy_file = /dev/urandom
session.hash_function = sha256
session.hash_bits_per_character = 5
```

The purpose is to secure "site.php", I include "session.php" in this file, with a cookie so you are only able to see the content of "site.php" with a cookie. So without a cookie if I want to go to site.php I get redirected to index.php but if I type:

```
curl https://<mysite>/site.php
```

On a client machine I get the source code of site.php without having a cookie. How can I secure this that even with "curl" you can not see the source code?

Greetings

EDIT: I was not clear enough, I mean I can see (with curl) the HTML/JS source code of "site.php" NOT the PHP source code.

Comment: Maybe this helps to find the problem: See if it matches with your scripts: http://www.coderslexicon.com/really-simple-php-login-logout-script-example/

Comment: Do you actually get the source code (php-code) of `start.php`? Then there's something else wrong. Making a curl request shouldn't give you the source code, that request should also pass through the web server and PHP interpreter. If it is the HTML you get, try to add `exit;` after all your `header('location:....')`-calls to stop the execution of the page and send the header straight away.

Comment: Also I think you first need to do `session_start()` with no arguments. As you could only pass options there (http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) but not setting the keys like you are trying.

Comment: @caramba - The OP's version of `session_start()` is actually taken from one of the examples (example #4) on that exact page so, I would say that it should be valid. However, since the code actually _does_ set session values and the example is only `read_and_close`, it should be omitted for that reason.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Thank you all for pointing out that I need to write "session_start()" at the beginning of the file. It is such a simple solution. THANK YOU

Answer (score 0):

Do:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['login_user'])) {
  header("location:index.php");
  die();
}
```

Instead of:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['login_user']))
  header("location:index.php");
```

`header("location:index.php")` just sends a header to tell the browser to redirect, but it doesn't abort the code/output.